# как загрузить артефакт сборки на bintray?

Tags: c++, build

На bintray же можно загружать не dep-пакеты?
использую

```
curl -T ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/bin/server -uk-morozov:$BINTRAY_API_KEY https://api.bintray.com/content/k-morozov/AppChat/Chat/$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER/server
```

но получаю ошибку на travis:

```
{"message":"Failed to resolve package name"}
```

Хотя в документации написано:

> You can upload any file to Bintray using:
>
> ```
> curl -T <FILE.EXT> -uk-morozov:<API_KEY> https://api.bintray.com/content/k-morozov/AppChat/<YOUR_COOL_PACKAGE_NAME>/<VERSION_NAME>/<FILE_TARGET_PATH>
> ```